# Help with url rewrite

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

How can I turn a URL like:

`http://site.com/?project=5`

into:

`http://site.com/project/5/`

?

I was looking the rewrite doc here:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Rewrite#Examples

and came up with this

```
// Adding a new rule
function my_insert_rewrite_rules( $rules )
{
  $newrules = array();
  $newrules['(project)/(\d*)$'] = 'index.php?project=$matches[2]';
  return $newrules + $rules;
}

// Adding the id var so that WP recognizes it
function my_insert_query_vars( $vars )
{
    array_push($vars, 'project');
    return $vars;
}

add_filter( 'rewrite_rules_array','my_insert_rewrite_rules' );
add_filter( 'query_vars','my_insert_query_vars' );
add_action( 'wp', 'test');

function test()
{
 global $wp_rewrite;
 $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
 if(isset($_GET['project'])){
   echo $_GET['project'];
   exit;
 }

};
```

but it doesn't work when I access for example http://site.com/project/2/

Comment: what is a project? a custom post type?

Comment: no. it's nothing, just a query variable i'm using

Comment: you can pass project as a query var, but your destination has to be *something*, like a page.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The PHP code is not enough, you need to edit your .htaccess file correspondingly. (You can do this with `$wp_rewrite->mod_rewrite_rules();` somehow, or edit it manually.) However, be aware that URL rewriting is complicated stuff - are you sure you need it? If you are using pretty permalinks for posts/pages, chances are this will bork it up.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way to do this is to create a page, and give it the slug project.

Then add your rewrite rule and query var:

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_insert_rewrite_rules' );
function my_insert_rewrite_rules(){
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'project/([0-9]+)/?$',
        'index.php?pagename=project&project=$matches[1]',
        'top' );
}

add_filter( 'query_vars', 'my_insert_query_vars' );
function my_insert_query_vars( $query_vars ){
    $query_vars[] = 'project';
    return $query_vars;
}
```

Then in your template, use `get_query_var('project');` to retrieve the value of project.